# Let V = C[0,1] and W = {$f \in C[0,1] | f(1) \leq 0$} is W a subspace of the vector space V

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I've shown that W is closed under addition and contains the 0 function but I'm a bit confused about how scalar multiplication works for C[0,1] so I'm not sure whether W is closed under it.

If f(1) = -1 and the scalar c = -1 then cf(1) > 0 so cf(x) is not contained in W. But can the scalar be a negative number in this context or does it need to be between 0 and 1 because f is in C[0,1]?

Answer (score 1):

No, the scalar does not need to be between $0$ and $1$. As you have found, the set $W$ fails to be a vector subspace of $V$ because it is not closed under scalar multiplication.